# Regular expression removes extra whitespaces

Tags: regex, vb.net, string

I have a string where I want to remove any special characters such as ~ or * etc.

I was using regex "[ ](?=[ ])|[^-_,A-Za-z0-9 ]+"

Then I noticed that along with special characters it removed extra whitespace. For instance if a string has a space between words that is larger than 1, it changes it to a single space. For instance if a string is

```
  ~ my test   123    456
```

I want `my test   123    456` returned but instead I get `my test 123 456`

so I changed `[ ](?=[ ])|[^-_,A-Za-z0-9 ]+ to [ ][^-_,A-Za-z0-9 ]+`

but now ~ does not get removed from the string. I get `~ my test   123    456`

The code I use is as follows:

```
line = Regex.Replace(line, "[ ][^-_A-Za-z0-9 ]+", "").Trim()
```

Comment: a single example wouldn't be enough. Post some more..

Comment: Anything wrong with `Regex.Replace(line, "[^\w\s]", "").Trim()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this,

```
line = Regex.Replace(line, @"[^-,\w ]", "").Trim()
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lB9jE8/1)

Comment: but why do I need to match spaces? I just want spaces to be ignored and left alone

Comment: @ElenaDBA then why the spaces before `~` got removed. Check your expected output.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I think that's because he `trim`med the string at the end.

Comment: [^-_,A-Za-z0-9 ] seem to have worked. Could you please change your answer again, so I could accept it without confusion for anyone viewing this question later

Comment: @ElenaDBA: `[^-,\w ]` is the same as `[^-_,A-Za-z0-9 ]`, just shorter.